# How can i create the dynamic search,select and display in html using javascript or ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, select, search

Am searching for the dynamic search and select the data from the database and i want it to shows the input keyword related data in the select box .I am writing the code in html which language is preferable for me to write the dynamic select and search text box.

[Dynamic search and select[][1]][1]

Here is the link where i got the static search and select box i want same in dynamic type.
  https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename%3Dtryhtml5_datalist&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1520486059985000&usg=AFQjCNFp5AF5Yt7540e8fSX_rzG7OyOpOg

Comment: I don't really understand your question. So you want the value to be different from the thing that is displayed in the dropdown?

Comment: Please add some clarity to your question.

Comment: actually i want to display the values from the database when i input the keyword and search the relevant data in database it has to show the data related to that in the database